# Multiple Small DOM operation vs One large DOM operation

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

This is more a question about best practices. When trying to apply MVC-like design pattern in a web application, I often find myself wonder how I should go about updating the View.

For example, if I am to update View_1 who has X number of elements. Is it better to:

A: iterate through each of the X elements, figuring out which ones need to be updated and apply the DOM change at a very fine granularity.

or

B: using the data supplied by Model or some other data structure to regenerate the markup for this entire View and all its enclosing elements, and replace the root element of View_1 in one DOM manipulation?

Correct me if I am mistaken. I heard that rendering engines are usually more efficient at replacing at large chunk of the DOM in one go, than multiple smaller DOM operations. If that is the case then approach B is superior. However, even using template engines, I still sometimes find it difficult to avoid rewrite markups for parts of the view that aren't changed.

I looked into the source code for project Bespin before the renamed it. I distinctly remember that they implemented some sort of rendering loop mechanism where DOM operations are queued and applied in fixed time intervals, much like how games manage their frames. This is similar to Approach A. I can also see the rationales behind this approach. The small DOM operations applied in such manner keeps the UI responsive (especially important for a web text editor). Also this way, the application can be made more efficient by only update the elements that needs to be changed. Static text and aesthetic elements can remain untouched.

Those are my arguments for both sides. What do you guys think? Are we looking for a happy medium somewhere, or one approach is by and large superior?

Also, are there any good books/papers/sites on this particular topic?

(let's assume the web app in question is interaction heavy with many dynamic updates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 years of working with various web technologies, I think I finally found a great balance between the two approach: virtual DOM

Libraries like vdom, Elm, mithril.js, and to some extend Facebook React track a thin abstraction of the actual DOM, figures out what needs to be changed, and tries to apply the smallest possible DOM change.

e.g.

https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom/tree/master/vdom

Answer (score 2):

It's true that rendering engines usually handle change in large chunks faster than multiple small changes.

tl;dr: The bespin way would be ideal, and if you can, do it in a worker.

Depending on the size of the amount of changes you might want to try to start a worker and do the calculation of the changes inside the worker since long running JS lock up the UI. You might consider using the following flow:

1. Create a object with a part of the dom tree and also the parent id.
2. Stringify the object to JSON
3. Start a worker
4. Pass in the stringified object into the worker
5. Receive and parse the string.
6. Work on changing all the necessary parts of the dom tree that you passed in.
7. Stringify the object again.
8. Pass the object back to the main thread.
9. Parse and extract new dom tree.
10. Insert into the dom again.

This will be faster if there are many changes and a small tree. If it's a big tree and few changes just doing the changes locally in a copy of the real DOM tree will be faster and then updating the DOM in one go.

**Also read googles sites about page speed:**

https://code.google.com/speed/articles/

**And especially this article:**

https://code.google.com/speed/articles/javascript-dom.html